# Which namescape should I add to use System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration

Tags: c#, reference

Which namescape/reference should I add to use following

```
System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration
```

in my code?

Comment: -1 for extreme laziness. Putting that in google will give you the MSDN page of that method as the very first result. Navigating to the containing class will show the assembly you need to reference

Comment: It is clearly you didn't **any** research. So, this is not a real question. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 5):

Here how I find the answer..

- I opened the the site called [Google](https://www.google.com.tr/).
- Wrote your code and click `Search` button.
- And it opens me [`WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration Method (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151456.aspx) page.

And the namespace part, it says;

```
Namespace:  System.Web.Configuration
Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)
```

As you can see, it is not hard to find this kind of basic answers. My aim is why I wrote these steps, I don't want to give you fish, I try to teach to how you can catch one.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

```
Namespace:  System.Web.Configuration
Assembly:  System.Web (in System.Web.dll)
```